# where can i find metadata of all the amazon cloud services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I searching for what are the metadata that AWS uses for each and every service. For AWS instance it uses ami-id, ami_launch-index, hostname, instance-action and many more as the metadata like wise where i can find metadata for all the services like EBS, VPN....

Reference
Information obtained from Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud User Guide for Microsoft Windows Instances pdf pg no : 232 – 242

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are interested in knowing the properties of the each AWS Resource / Service and not the meta-data. I don't think there is a straight answer. The work around what I can recommend is using the AWS CloudFormation's Syntax definition of each AWS Resource.

For Example :

**EC2 Instance** is represented by the following syntax. Not all of them are mandatory. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html

Look at the KEYS of the **Key**:Value pair provided below [ **`"AvailabilityZone"`** : String ]

```
{
   "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
   "Properties" : {
      "AvailabilityZone" : String,
      "BlockDeviceMappings" : [ EC2 Block Device Mapping, ... ],
      "DisableApiTermination" : Boolean,
      "EbsOptimized" : Boolean,
      "IamInstanceProfile" : String,
      "ImageId" : String,
      "InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior" : String,
      "InstanceType" : String,
      "KernelId" : String,
      "KeyName" : String,
      "Monitoring" : Boolean,
      "NetworkInterfaces" : [ EC2 Network Interface, ... ],
      "PlacementGroupName" : String,
      "PrivateIpAddress" : String,
      "RamdiskId" : String,
      "SecurityGroupIds" : [ String, ... ],
      "SecurityGroups" : [ String, ... ],
      "SourceDestCheck" : Boolean,
      "SsmAssociations" : [ SSMAssociation, ... ]
      "SubnetId" : String,
      "Tags" : [ Resource Tag, ... ],
      "Tenancy" : String,
      "UserData" : String,
      "Volumes" : [ EC2 MountPoint, ... ],
      "AdditionalInfo" : String
   }
}
```

**For VPC** [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc.html]

```
{
   "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPC",
   "Properties" : {
      "CidrBlock" : String,
      "EnableDnsSupport" : Boolean,
      "EnableDnsHostnames" : Boolean,
      "InstanceTenancy" : String,
      "Tags" : [ Resource Tag, ... ]
   }
}
```

**For EBS Volume** [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volume.html]

```
{
   "Type":"AWS::EC2::Volume",
   "Properties" : {
      "AutoEnableIO" : Boolean,
      "AvailabilityZone" : String,
      "Encrypted" : Boolean,
      "Iops" : Number,
      "KmsKeyId" : String,
      "Size" : String,
      "SnapshotId" : String,
      "Tags" : [ Resource Tag, ... ],
      "VolumeType" : String
   }
}
```

The CloudFormation Resource Page has details for most of the items [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html]. Below is the current list as of today [7 Jan 2016]

- AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
- AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
- AWS::AutoScaling::LifecycleHook
- AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
- AWS::AutoScaling::ScheduledAction
- AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication
- AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource
- AWS::CloudFormation::Init
- AWS::CloudFormation::Interface
- AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
- AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition
- AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle
- AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
- AWS::CloudTrail::Trail
- AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
- AWS::CodeDeploy::Application
- AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentConfig
- AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup
- AWS::CodePipeline::CustomActionType
- AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
- AWS::Config::ConfigRule
- AWS::Config::ConfigurationRecorder
- AWS::Config::DeliveryChannel
- AWS::DataPipeline::Pipeline
- AWS::DirectoryService::MicrosoftAD
- AWS::DirectoryService::SimpleAD
- AWS::DynamoDB::Table
- AWS::EC2::CustomerGateway
- AWS::EC2::DHCPOptions
- AWS::EC2::EIP
- AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation
- AWS::EC2::Instance
- AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
- AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl
- AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry
- AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
- AWS::EC2::NetworkInterfaceAttachment
- AWS::EC2::PlacementGroup
- AWS::EC2::Route
- AWS::EC2::RouteTable
- AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
- AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress
- AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
- AWS::EC2::SpotFleet
- AWS::EC2::Subnet
- AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation
- AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
- AWS::EC2::Volume
- AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment
- AWS::EC2::VPC
- AWS::EC2::VPCDHCPOptionsAssociation
- AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
- AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
- AWS::EC2::VPCPeeringConnection
- AWS::EC2::VPNConnection
- AWS::EC2::VPNConnectionRoute
- AWS::EC2::VPNGateway
- AWS::EC2::VPNGatewayRoutePropagation
- AWS::ECS::Cluster
- AWS::ECS::Service
- AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
- AWS::EFS::FileSystem
- AWS::EFS::MountTarget
- AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster
- AWS::ElastiCache::ParameterGroup
- AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup
- AWS::ElastiCache::SecurityGroup
- AWS::ElastiCache::SecurityGroupIngress
- AWS::ElastiCache::SubnetGroup
- AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
- AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
- AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
- AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
- AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
- AWS::IAM::AccessKey
- AWS::IAM::Group
- AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
- AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
- AWS::IAM::Policy
- AWS::IAM::Role
- AWS::IAM::User
- AWS::IAM::UserToGroupAddition
- AWS::Kinesis::Stream
- AWS::KMS::Key
- AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
- AWS::Lambda::Function
- AWS::Lambda::Permission
- AWS::Logs::Destination
- AWS::Logs::LogGroup
- AWS::Logs::LogStream
- AWS::Logs::MetricFilter
- AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter
- AWS::OpsWorks::App
- AWS::OpsWorks::ElasticLoadBalancerAttachment
- AWS::OpsWorks::Instance
- AWS::OpsWorks::Layer
- AWS::OpsWorks::Stack
- AWS::RDS::DBCluster
- AWS::RDS::DBClusterParameterGroup
- AWS::RDS::DBInstance
- AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup
- AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup
- AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroupIngress
- AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
- AWS::RDS::EventSubscription
- AWS::RDS::OptionGroup
- AWS::Redshift::Cluster
- AWS::Redshift::ClusterParameterGroup
- AWS::Redshift::ClusterSecurityGroup
- AWS::Redshift::ClusterSecurityGroupIngress
- AWS::Redshift::ClusterSubnetGroup
- AWS::Route53::HealthCheck
- AWS::Route53::HostedZone
- AWS::Route53::RecordSet
- AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
- AWS::S3::Bucket
- AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
- AWS::SDB::Domain

Answer (score 0):

Try using AWS CLI.
You can execute the describe commands of the various services to see and understand the metadata